# what is blockchain.info testnet api url?

Tags: blockchain, api, testnet

there is a testnet for blockchain.info [here](https://testnet.blockchain.info/) but I can't find a url for calling api(s) in testnet as such we have in main network

on main network
https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive?xpub=$xpub&callback=$callback_url&key=$key

and for example on testnet
https://api.testnet.blockchain.info/v2/receive?xpub=$xpub&callback=$callback_url&key=$key

is there anybody know where the testnet api url is?
Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked https://testnet.blockchain.info/api?

For instance, to get a raw tx:

https://testnet.blockchain.info/rawtx/tx_id

Comment: How to create new wallet address and send coins from one wallet to another in https://testnet.blockchain.info this API?  https://testnet.blockchain.info/q/addressbalance//mx9nK1Ty5uGvHcUCAXXHTMvkQC8pTNaKfr this one to get balance similarly how to exchnge coins?

Comment: is blockchain info API working? I'm trying to get some data using your endpoints, but I'm not able to.